# Translation from JS to Java

Tags: javascript, java

I need decode  from Base64 to Hex( ex, **AAAAAAAAnH0=  -> 0000000000009C7D,AAAAAAAAALQ= -> 00000000000000B4**) since on this site - http://tomeko.net/online_tools/base64.php?lang=en
The decoding functions stores on this site  in the plain text:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    var hD='0123456789ABCDEF';
    function dec2hex(d) {
        var h = hD.substr(d&15,1);
        while (d>15) {
            d>>=4;
            h=hD.substr(d&15,1)+h;
        }
        if (document.frmConvert.chbLowercaseOutput.checked) {
            h = h.toLowerCase();
        }
        return h;
    }

    var keyStr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/="
    function base64_decode(input) {
        var output = new Array();
        var chr1, chr2, chr3;
        var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
        var i = 0;

        var orig_input = input;
        input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");
        if (orig_input != input)
            alert ("Warning! Characters outside Base64 range in input string ignored.");
        if (input.length % 4) {
            alert ("Error: Input length is not a multiple of 4 bytes.");
            return "";
        }

        var j=0;
        while (i < input.length) {

            enc1 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc2 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc3 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc4 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));

            chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
            chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
            chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;

            output[j++] = chr1;
            if (enc3 != 64)
              output[j++] = chr2;
            if (enc4 != 64)
              output[j++] = chr3;

        }
        return output;
    }


    function ShowDecodedAsText(val)
    {
        var target = document.getElementById('divDecodedText'); 
        target.innerHTML = val;    
    }     

    function Convert() {
        var output = base64_decode(document.frmConvert.encoded.value);
        var separator = "";
        if (document.frmConvert.chbSeparator.checked)
            separator = " 0x";
        var hexText = "";
        var htmlStr = "<p style=\"font-family: courier new, monospace\"><b>";
        for (i=0; i<output.length; i++) {
          hexText = hexText + separator + (output[i]<16?"0":"") + dec2hex(output[i]);
          if (output[i] >= 32 && output[i] <= 126)
          {
            switch(String.fromCharCode(output[i])) {
            case '&': htmlStr += "&amp;";
              break;
            case '<': htmlStr += "&lt;";
              break;
            case '>': htmlStr += "&gt;";
              break;
            case '"': htmlStr += "&quot;";
              break;
            case '\'': htmlStr += "&#039;";
              break;
            default: htmlStr += String.fromCharCode(output[i]);
            }          
          }
          else {
            htmlStr += "<i>[" + output[i] + "]<" + "/i>";
          }
        }
        htmlStr += "<" + "/b><" + "/p>";  // stupid W3C validator...
        document.frmConvert.hex.value = hexText;

        ShowDecodedAsText(htmlStr);   
    }

    function ConvertToFile() {
      Convert();
      createFileFromHex(document.frmConvert.hex.value, document.frmConvert.filename.value);
    } 


</script>
```

I need to implement everything in Java and I wrote class:

```
public class TomaszDecoder {

    private  final String hD="0123456789ABCDEF";
    private  final String keyStr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";

    private final int HEX_COUNT = 15;
    private String dec2hex(int d) {

        String h = substr(d & HEX_COUNT);
        while (d>15) {
            d>>=4;
            h = substr(d & HEX_COUNT)+h;
        }

        return h;
    }

    private String substr(int start) {
        if (start < 0)
            start = HEX_COUNT + start;
        return hD.substring(start,start+1);
    }


    private String base64_decode(String input) {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        int chr1, chr2, chr3;
        int enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
        int i = 0;

       /* var orig_input = input;
        replace(input,'/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g', "");
        if (input.length % 4) {
            status = "Error: Input length is not a multiple of 4 bytes";
            return [output, status];
        }*/

        int j=0;
        while (i < input.length()) {

            enc1 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc2 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc3 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc4 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));

            chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
            chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
            chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;

            output.append(chr1);
            if (enc3 != 64)
                output.append(chr2);
            if (enc4 != 64)
                output.append(chr3);

        }
       /* var status;
        if (orig_input != input) {
            status = "Warning! Characters outside Base64 range in input string ignored.";
        } else {
            status = "";
        }*/
        return output.toString();
    }

    public String convertFromBase64(String base64String) {
        StringBuilder hexText =  new StringBuilder();
        String separator = "";
        /*if (document.frmConvert.chbSeparator.checked)
            separator = " 0x";*/
       // var lines = document.frmConvert.encoded.value.split('\n');

         char[] output = base64_decode(base64String).toCharArray();
            for (int j=0; j<output.length; j++) {
                hexText.append(separator + (output[j]<16?"0":"") + dec2hex(output[j]));
            }

            return hexText.toString();

    }
}
```

But he gives a different result, I really hope for your help in solving the problem.

**input - AAAAAAAAALQ=, output - 30303030303030313830 (correct - 00000000000000B4)**

Comment: Can you show us a certain input where the outputs are different? With other words, what exactly is the difference?

Comment: input - AAAAAAAAALQ=, output - 30303030303030313830 (correct - 00000000000000B4)

Comment: Don't post those results here in the comments, but instead, please use the [edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47547368/edit) below your question to add details.

Comment: Are there any constriants preventing you from using the built-in (since Java 6) [`DataTypeConverter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#printBase64Binary%28byte[]%29)? It's trivial with this tool: `String base64StringToHexString(String base64String) { return DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(base64String)); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I myself solved my problem. I use [rhino](https://github.com/mozilla/rhino)

```
private void runScript(String javaScriptCode,String functionNameInJavaScriptCode,Object[] params) {
    org.mozilla.javascript.Context rhino = org.mozilla.javascript.Context.enter();
    rhino.setOptimizationLevel(-1);
    try {
        Scriptable scope = rhino.initStandardObjects();

        rhino.evaluateString(scope,javaScriptCode , "JavaScript", 1, null);

        // Get the functionName defined in JavaScriptCode
        Object obj = scope.get(functionNameInJavaScriptCode, scope);

        if (obj instanceof org.mozilla.javascript.Function) {
            org.mozilla.javascript.Function jsFunc = (org.mozilla.javascript.Function) obj;


            // Call the function with params
            Object jsResult =
                    jsFunc.call(rhino, scope, scope, params);
            // Parse the jsResult object to a String
            String result = org.mozilla.javascript.Context.toString(jsResult);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),result,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    finally {
        org.mozilla.javascript.Context.exit();
    }

}
```

call method

```
String script = readTextFromAssetsFile("tomasz.js");
runScript(script,"convert",new Object[]{"AAAAAAAAnH0="});
```